# No output on the graphics card

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I am trying to install an old graphics card in an old computer. The card is an HIS IceQ X2 Radeon HD 7970 3go and the mobo an ECS H62H2-M12. The power supply does not have the two 8 pins connector recquired to power the card, so I used two adapters 2xMOLEX to 8 pins.

Before installing the new card, I uninstalled all the software and drivers related to the old one (a Radeon HD 5450 from MSI). I then installed the new card and connected the PC with the DVI and HDMI ports (not at the same time, just to say I tried both) but nothing happened. Worst: the lights on the mouse and the keyboard were off, so maybe the PC didn't even boot properly (I don't have any speaker or screen on the mobo to know if the POST is ok).

Of course, I then tried to connect the monitor to the VGA port of the motherboard... And still nothing. The only solution I found was to unplug the 8 pins connector powering the graphics card to get an output via the mobo. But then Windows tells me that there is a problem with the graphics card, and the AMD driver installer fails because it does not detect the card...

This is the first time I try to do something like this. I decided to train on an old machine, but I did not expect it to be that difficult... Please help my noobie ass understanding what's going on, because I am clueless :(

Comment: To summarise: You have a card rated for up to 250W power.  You do not have the proper power connectors in the PSU (not just for, but also able to generate at least 150W per 8 pin connector).  You took some molex connector (which probably supply way less) and made it physically fit, but things do not work,...

Comment: So you are telling me the Power supply is the problem ? Because I don't think I can change it, it is part of the case...

Comment: It probably is. What you describe fits the symtoms of insufficient power and you made some connection which physically fit but which may not work (dending on your PSU and its output. And with that I do not just mean total max rated power).  Think of it of connecting a fire hose to a garden house and thinking 'both supply water. Done!'.   Having said that. Testing the card of the whole system with a different PSU which has the right power connector would also be a good step to take,

Comment: Unfortunatly this is the only system I have, so I will just assume you are right and that I picked the wrong graphics card for my system. This is why I started this little project: try some stuff, possibly do some mistakes along the way but ultimatly learn a lot about PC hardware. Thanks a lot for your help and have a nice day / evening / night :)